# Uniqueness of a particular order on a line

Tags: euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

This question arises probably from my astonishingly poor knowledge of classical euclidean geometry's axioms.

Let $ l $ be a line. I have to admit I never understood how we can say that $ l $ is in one-to-one correspondence with the real line (as some texbooks write). As last premise, I should also say that I never taken any formal logic/MT course.

Actually, we can build a bijection between a subset $ \left\{P + tv\right\}_{t\in\mathbb R} $ of $ \mathbb R^2 $ and $ \mathbb R $, in a straightforward way; in other words, we can say that some objects of a *model* of euclidean geometry can be putted in one-to-one correspondence with $ \mathbb R $.

My question now is: In classical axiomatic geometry, is it an axiom that given a line $ l $, and two points $ O $ and $ A $ laying on $ l $, there is a **unique** "order relation", "ordering", such that $ O $ *precedes* $ A $? Or is the existence of such a relation (to be intended as a predicate in two variables, I think) *precedes* actually given as an axiom, and its uniqueness can be deduced from other stuff?

And how about **the $ \mathbb R^n $ version of this statement**? Given a set of the form of $ \left\{P + tv\right\}_{t\in\mathbb R} $ (what in my mind and in Apostol's calculus book is called a *line*), and two points $ O,A\in l $, what can we say about putting an order relation on $ l $? From my point of view, the mapping $ t\mapsto O + t(A-O) $ induces an ordering $ {\leqq_{(O,A)}} $ on $ l $, such that $ O\leqq_{(O,A)}A $; but in what sense should I think about that "uniqueness"?

Comment: There are infinitely many different linear isomorphisms between a line and the real line $\mathbb{R}$, depending on where you want the origin and how much you want the line to be dilated or contracted. Once you've chosen one of these linear isomorphisms, it induces an order relation, so there are also infinitely many different order relations possible on your real line.

Comment: Consider the line $ l = \left\{P + tv\right\}_{t\in\mathbb R} $, and two points $ O $ and $ A $ on it. We can write $ l $ in two ways, namely as $ l = \left\{O + t(A - O)\right\} $ and $ l = \left\{A + t(O - A)\right\} $. The two mappings $ \mathbb{R}\to l $ 
\begin{align*}
l_{(O,A)} &\colon t\mapsto O + t(A - O)\\
l_{(A,O)} &\colon t\mapsto A + t(O - A)
\end{align*}
induce two different orders on $ l $, i.e., $ {\leqq_{(O,A)}} $ and $ {\leqq_{(A,O)}} $, such that, for all $ X = l_{(O,A)}(s) = l_{(A,O)}(t) $ and $ Y = l_{(O,A)}(s^\prime) = l_{(A,O)}(t^\prime) $ [continues below]

Comment: [i.e., here]\begin{align*}
X\leqq_{(A,O)}Y &\iff s\leqq s^\prime\\
X\leqq_{(A,O)}Y &\iff t\leqq t^\prime\\
\end{align*}
The point $ O $ precedes $ A $ with the first relation, while is $ A $ that precedes $ O $ with $ {\leqq_{(A,O)}} $.

Now let $ \varphi $ be a bijection $ \mathbb R\cong l $, and suppose that, considering the order $ {\leqq_\varphi} $ it induces on $ l $, is $ O\leqq_\varphi A $. Is it true that $ {\leqq_\varphi} = {\leqq_{(O,A)}} $?

The point is that I want to put an order on $ l $ such that the "origin" $ O $ actually precedes $ A $.

Comment: You could define an order on the reals which swaps $0$ and $1$ (or indeed any two arbitrary points) order relation wise, i.e. $0 <_n b \iff 1 < b$ and $1 <_n b \iff 0 <  b$, where $<_n$ is our new order relation and $<$ the canonical order. You can do a similar operation on the order you have defined. Or do you have additional properties for your order in mind besides $O < A$ and it being a total order relation?

Comment: Maybe. What if we restrict ourselves to order relations induced by affine mappings $ \mathbb R\to l $? Note that both $ l_{(O,A)} $ and $ l_{(A,O)} $ are affine. I think I will be happy enough proving that the following holds: given a line $ l = \{P + tv\}\subset\mathbb R^n $ and two points $ O,A\in l $, if $ O $ precedes $ A $ with the order $ {\leqq_{(O,A)}} $ induced by the map $ l_{(O,A)}\colon t\mapsto O + t(A - O) $, and the same happens with the order $ {\leqq_\varphi} $ induced by any affine isomorphism $ \varphi\colon\mathbb R\to l $, then $ {\leqq_\phi} = {\leqq_{(O,A)}} $.

Comment: Yes, that is definitely true. Just write down the affine isomorphism and derive the conditions on its parameters in order for $O \leq A$ to hold.